# Map an array to set empty elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given:

```
let input = [0, 1, 2,,,,,7]
```

I want to get:

```
let output = [, 1, 22, 333, 4444, 55555, 666666, 7777777]
```

(i.e. *value* equal *key* times the *key*)

**How can I `map` (or equivalent) input including *empty* values?**
 If I do `input.map()` I will get `[, 1, 22,,,,,7777777]` because `map` will *-of course-* not iterate *empty* values. Data can be arbitrary, strings, objects, numbers, etc. Using numbers in this example for simplicity.

Comment: Does it have to be `input = [0, 1, 2,,,,,7]` or it it possible to simply use `Array.from({ length: 8 }, (_, index) => index)` instead, in your use-case, or just `Array.from({ length: 8 }, (_, index) => String(index).repeat(index))` to begin with?

Comment: _“Data can be arbitrary, strings, objects, numbers, etc.”_ — so what’s the algorithm for “arbitrary” data? You assume that integers can be filled in in the missing spots. What’s the expected result for `[1, 2, 3, , , 99]`? What’s the expected result for `[1, 2, "a", 99]`?

Comment: @user4642212 The problem is not the map result. But rather how to "map" (or whatever) empty values. For example `[1,,1]` could yield to `[{...}, {...}, {...}]`.

Comment: So you want `arr.fill().map(...)`?

Comment: i would suggest something like this `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((el, index) => Array(el).fill(null).map(() => index).join(""))`

Comment: @adelriosantiago _“could yield”_ really isn’t specific enough. The second argument to [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) takes care of empty slots, and it’s like a `map`. Use the second argument to get the index of an array slot.

Comment: @Teiem The `null` in `.fill` isn’t necessary. Your code is equivalent to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((el, index) => Array(el).fill().map(() => index).join(""))`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can `fill` the array before applying a mapping function so that all indexes are iterated over, including empty ones.

```
let result = input.fill().map((_,index)=>{/*...*/});
```

The mapping function provided as the second argument to `Array.from` can be similarly used.

```
let result = Array.from({length: input.length}, (_, index)=>{/*...*/});
```

Spread syntax does not ignore empty slots, so we can create a copy of the array with spread syntax and `map` over that. This has an added advantage of having the elements at each index available as well.

```
let result = [...input].map((elem, idx)=>{/*...*/});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach too verbose but it works, with for loop you can loop through null values

```js
arr=[0, 1, 2,,,,,7]
res=[]
f=false
for(let i=0;i<arr.length-1;i++){
  if(arr[i]!=undefined){
      res.push(Number(String(arr[i]).repeat(arr[i])))
      //f=false
  }
  if(arr[i]==undefined&&f==false){
    n= arr[i-1]  
    f=true
    res.push(Number(String(n+1).repeat(n+1)))}
    if(f==true && arr[i]==undefined){
     n=Number(res[res.length-1].toString().charAt(0))+1
      res.push(Number(String(n).repeat(n)))
    }
}
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

map() can't include empty values. *[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp#:%7E:text=The%20map()%20method%20creates,for%20array%20elements%20without%20values.)*

> map() does not execute the function for array elements without values.

So, either iterate the array with a for-loop:

```
out = [];
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var item = input[i];
    if (item != null)
        out[i] = item.toString().repeat(item);
}
```

Or create another *mapx()* functor:

```
Array.prototype.mapx = function(fn) {
    var out = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        var item = this[i];
        // if (item == null) item = sherlockHolmesKnow();
        out[i] = fn(item, i);
    }
    return out;
};
```

and apply on the input:

```
input.mapx( (val, index) => (val == null ? null : (val+'').repeat(val)) )
```

which yields *["", "1", "22", null, null, null, null, "7777777"]*.

Let's skip the AI part of clever guessing the numbers in the empty slots.

Comment: Why create an entire new prototype method instead of simply using `input.fill(null).map((val) => (val === undefined ? null : String(val).repeat(val)))` or `Array.from(input, (val) => (val === undefined ? null : String(val).repeat(val)))`?

Comment: __Array.fill()__ will alter the contents of __input__. __Array.from()__  is fine, 
only except it created a temporary array. whatever there's more than one way to do it. I'll go with the for-loop myself :)

Comment: @XièJìléi - `Array.from` doesn't require creating a temporary array, it accepts a mapping function as its second argument: `const result = Array.from(original, () => /*...*/);`